# Trying to read values from an XML feed and display them in PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplexml

I'm trying to display values from this xml feed:
http://www.scorespro.com/rss/live-soccer.xml

In my PHP code I have the following loop but it does not display the results on my page:

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.scorespro.com/rss/live-soccer.xml");

    echo $xml->getName() . "<br>";

    foreach($xml->children() as $item)
    {
        echo $item->getName() . ": " . $item->name . "<br>";
    }
?>
```

For some reason it only shows:

```
rss
channel:
```

I'm fairly new to how XML works so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any "name" in the XML. Did you mean `$item->title`?

Comment: If you're only concerned about RSS (or Atom), you might want to look at [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/). It is way easier to use than working with XML and provides helpers to access data relevant for feeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get actual data from `$xml->channel->item` so use like below

```
$items = $xml->channel->item;    
foreach($items as $item) {
  $title = $item->title;
  $link = $item->link;
  $pubDate = $item->pubDate;
  $description = $item->description;
}
```

**[DEMO.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0DwnMe)**

Answer (score -1):

you can use below code

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($url);
if (!$dom) {
    echo 'Error while parsing the document';
    exit;
}
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
$data = $xml->channel->item;
```